# Receive traffic from different sub-domains but send to backend as a single domain

Tags: nginx, proxy, domain

I am having a server with Nginx as server & a rails application in the backend. At present, the rails application can only serve to a single domain at once. I will, however, be creating and destroying servers with this application every hour.

So, I want to configure the server to respond to any subdomains. But the backend application should always see a fixed domain.

For example if I get a request from `sub1.A.com`, `sub2.A.com` etc... backend should always receive the request as sub.A.com.

I also don't want to a load balancer or reverse proxy or something outside the server. I am not sure what to search for this particular use case. What are the normal solution deployed etc...

My `nginx.conf` file:

```
server {
    server_name  domain.com;

     location ~ /\.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        allow all;
        root /var/www/letsencrypt;
        try_files $uri =404;
        break;
     }


     access_log  /var/log/nginx/bigbluebutton.access.log;

     # Handle RTMPT (RTMP Tunneling).  Forwards requests
     # to Red5 on port 5080

     location ~ (/open/|/close/|/idle/|/send/|/fcs/) {
          proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:5080;
          proxy_redirect     off;
          proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

          client_max_body_size       10m;
          client_body_buffer_size    128k;

          proxy_connect_timeout      90;
          proxy_send_timeout         90;
          proxy_read_timeout         90;

          proxy_buffering            off;
          keepalive_requests         1000000000;
      }

     # Handle desktop sharing tunneling.  Forwards
     # requests to Red5 on port 5080.
       location /deskshare {
           proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:5080;
           proxy_redirect     default;
           proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           client_max_body_size       10m;
           client_body_buffer_size    128k;
           proxy_connect_timeout      90;
           proxy_send_timeout         90;
           proxy_read_timeout         90;
           proxy_buffer_size          4k;
           proxy_buffers              4 32k;
           proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
           proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
           include    fastcgi_params;
       }

    # BigBlueButton landing page.
    # changed for making greelight primary
        location /old {
          root   /var/www/bigbluebutton-default;
          index  index.html index.htm;
      expires 1m;
        }

    # Make greelight primary
        location = / {
        return 307 /b;
        }

    # Include specific rules for record and playback
        include /etc/bigbluebutton/nginx/*.nginx;

        #error_page  404  /404.html;

        # Redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
                root   /var/www/nginx-default;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host =  domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


     listen   80;
     listen [::]:80;
     server_name  domain.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Comment: How do you pass requests to your backend? Using a `proxy_pass` directive? It would be better if you show the according part of your nginx config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This automated config by Certbot isn't very suitable for your needs. Change HTTP to HTTPS redirection block to this one:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    listen   [::]:80;
    server   .domain.com;
    return   301 https://$http_host$request_uri;
}
```

Make the following changes to your HTTPS block:

- use `server .domain.com;` instead of `server domain.com;` (this special form matches the `domain.com` domain and any of its subdomains);
- add `proxy_set_header Host "sub.domain.com";` directive to your location blocks where `proxy_pass` directive is used (assuming that `sub.domain.com` is the domain you want to be seen by your backend app).

Comment: Let me try and get back.